Screenshot of the Week #120 - Video Game Toilets
This contest is over.
previous contest | next contest
Hello and welcome to the 120th edition of the Screenshot of the Week!
To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! Artfaith's screenshot from deus-ex-mankind-divided won with 12 upvotes!


To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question, but please take note of the following:

One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
Stack Exchange’s Code of Conduct still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.
How long will the contest run?
We will accept submissions for a week, until 19:00 UTC of 2024-07-22, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.
After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2024-07-29, we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured for a week on the main site's photo widget.

Theme: Video Game Toilets
Looking for a little toilet humor? Inspired by a recent popular question, we're looking for the weird, wonderful and wacky world of videogame water closets.
As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks, and have compiled that suggestion process into a question of its own.  Additionally, there is the hall of fame you can check out that contains all the previous contest winners.

“Behold, children! The Chron-O-John!”
— Doctor Fred, revealing his time-travelling portable toilets.
day-of-the-tentacle


It reminds me that there were plenty of toilets in "Zombies ate my neghbors" which had a day of the tentacle secret easter egg level

Man, this was such a great game. Such fond memories

The greatest outfit in saints-row-the-third


Oh man thats a throw back

It's a throwback? Really? Now I'm old.

@ColeBusby its almost 15 years old now

No, I'm just out of high school... There's no way.... God dammit I'm old now. It's been a generation. Noooo!

That's one doomed space marine - taking a bathroom break.
brutal-doom mod playing the Hell on Earth starter pack.


Atma / Ultima Buster  - The Toilet Boss
final-fantasy-6


You could actually sit on the toilets in this game, and it would even have a flushing sound.

The toilet - Giger-style.

 Somebody ... 


This is in overwatch-2, in the map "Route 66".
I know this is in another map too, but I can't remember which...
It is a reference to Shrek's outhouse, where he comes out from in the first movie, and pestered in the 3rd movie.

Ah, now I get the "Somebody.." - I just needed to read 'Shrek' :D

Once told me....

@Joachim Hehe just a little easter egg for people to enjoy.

Did someone actually downvote this? It was at 5 earlier today, and now it's down to 4.

@Clockwork That, or someone removed an upvote. I can't check it. I guess someone doesn't like the hog or Smash Mouth...

@Clockwork Yes, somebody downvoted it. However, downvoting SOTW posts is meaningless since the score are based on total upvotes

@Joachim: Actually, you'd have to watch the movie, as the thing referenced is not in the book, which bears very little resemblance to the movie in the first place.

@jwodder I meant "read the word 'shrek'" :) The song immediately starts playing in my head :) I used to know that film entirely by memory. For some reason.

@Joachim It's an amazing movie. I re-watched it a few days ago.

@Wondercricket I hoped someone would continue the song, and now I'm disappointed

"You're talking to me?"
dont-escape-4-days-to-survive


Although this is more of a bathroom screenshot than a toilet one; you can barely see it in the foreground

It is a pretty bathroom.

Not gonna lie, that house in the game looks very tempting, if I didn't have to fight for survival.
